# SSRS - Set dynamic body height

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report that contains a number of charts.

Where a chart hits a certain amount of results it will resize dynamically using the below code:

```
=(1 + Count( Fields!groupedColumnName.Value, "MyDataset") / 2) & ” in”
```

The problem is that although the charts are resizing the body does not.

Current size parameters for the body of the report are set to A4 (Portrait):

Height: 29.7cm;
Width: 21cm;

Is there a way to set these values dynamically? It doesnt look like I can enter an expression.

Comment: If you set the ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace to true and manually made the report size massive. When the chart size changes it will expand and take up more space and the ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace  should remove the excess. At least that's how I think it would work. "Height: 29.7cm; Width: 21cm;" this is for printing. Seeing what you are trying to do I assume you won't be printing this report.

Comment: @Snowlockk printing is a possibility in the future but id just like to know I can offer the option of doing it either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question turned out to be quite simple.

There is a report property named InteractiveSize that allows you to set the size of the report when its rendered (not printed).

You simply set either the Width or Height value to '0' depending on your need.

[image]

Comment: I was wondering, when you set the interactive size, does that only handle a 0 MINIMUM size, or will it override the size for the PageSize if the dataset takes up more space?

I'm looking to do something similar but with the height, so that the scrollbar at the bottom of the page is more visible without scrolling down to see it when the dataset is smaller, but I don't want the size to get larger than the Maximum size for when my dataset is larger.

Comment: @NocFenix i believe setting interactive height to 0 causes it to pick up the default page size whereas you can override it by setting the size to what you need. Its worth a bit more experimentation though