# SSRS multiple line charts in one report

Tags: reporting-services, linechart, ssrs-2014

Need advice on how to display multiple line charts in one report? Currently charts are stretched out and on each other when viewing the report. Expected outcome:

[image: Expected]

[image: But this is how its displayed]

Comment: You can Refer the below Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42552392/ssrs-set-dynamic-body-height

Comment: @Roshan , thanks but it did not help

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of detail given on what exactly is happening with your report, but I think the solution would be to set up a second column to keep the charts from stretching too far.  If you click anywhere outside of the report boundaries, the report properties appear in the properties window.  Set `Columns` to 2, and `ColumnSpacing` to 0 unless you want to ensure a certain gap between charts.

[image: columns]

For more details on how this works, refer to the [MSDN page here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms159107(v=sql.105)) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms155816%28v%3Dsql.105%29).

This does have limitations, as the columns can only be rendered in PDF and Image formats.  You can also refer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015098/ssrs-how-to-build-a-simple-multi-column-report) for more information.

Comment: as you can see the first picture displays how many charts should be displayed. When rendered in browser, the charts get stretched out and duplicates (the image below). There must be only 6 line charts.